# Billboard object on the X and Y axis while rotating on the Z

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

For the last few days I've been trying to come up with a way to billboard an object on the X and Y axis and rotate it on the z axis simultaneously. Since this didn't seem possible using the .lookAt method(Please correct me if I'm wrong) I started reading up on Quaternions. I found that using the static method .slerp almost did the trick. I have the X and Y axis's pointing towards my camera but the z axis wont fully rotate. It starts to rotate but then jumps back to 0. Here's the code.

```
           function rotZ() 
        {

            var rotateAngle = Math.PI / .5 * delta;
            var appQuatS = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
            var appQuatC = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
            appQuatS.applyQuaternion( meshSprite.quaternion );
            appQuatC.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
            var qm = new THREE.Quaternion();
            THREE.Quaternion.slerp(meshSprite.quaternion, camera.quaternion, qm, 1);
            qm.set(qm.x,qm.y,rotateAngle,1);
            meshSprite.quaternion = qm;
            //meshSprite.quaternion.set(meshSprite.quaternion.x,meshSprite.quaternion.y,rotateAngle,1);
            meshSprite.quaternion.normalize();
            //meshSprite.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), rotateAngle);
            //meshSprite.updateMatrix();
        }
```

Is there any thing obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Consider using a `THREE.Sprite`, which always faces the camera and can rotate on its local z-axis. But update to r.62dev first, because recent sprite bugs have been fixed.

Comment: Cool thanks for the tip. Should using the .rotateOnAxis method work for rotating the THREE.Sprite?